# Computing Slim Extensions representing Ext

Tags: homological-algebra, algorithms, group-cohomology

Hey Everyone

Let $A$ be an algebra over a field (group rings $k[G]$ for group cohomology, the Steenrod Algebra).  We want to compute, say, $Ext_A(k,k)$, so let $F_*\to k$ be an $A$-free resolution.  Elements of $Ext^j_A(k,k)$ can be represented as Yoneda extensions, essentially exact sequence $k\to M_1 \to ... \to M_{j} \to k$, which we denote $\mathcal{X}$, and a chain map map $F_*\to \mathcal{X}$ with the cocycle, $F_{j+1}\to k$, on one side and the identity map $k\to k$ on the other.  Using pushouts one can, given a cocycle, generate $\mathcal{X}$, but the modules in $\mathcal{X}$ can be rather large.

My question is then this.  Is there a way to either generate a "small" extension (measured however you'd like, perhaps the size of an extension should be the largest dimension over $k$ in any bi-digree) representing a cocycle, or given the a Yoneda extension, is there a way to make some sort of local change to it that can make it "smaller" (in which case we can search for a "local optimum").

This question is motivated as a workaround to the problem presented by Bob Bruner's in http://www.math.wayne.edu/~rrb/papers/yoneda.pdf.

Thanks

Comment: The Steenrod Algebra is not of finite type.

Comment: Oops, Why on earth did I write finite type...  I must be typing without thinking.  

Comment: trivial, unless $G$ itself is graded.  

Comment: To be honest, I didn't mean to write "graded algebra of finite type".  I fixed the finite type part.  

Answer (score 4):

Assume that a projective resolution $P \to k$ over $A$ is given (as far as I understand,  Bruner is able to compute such a $P$ in a reasonable amount of time) and that $f: P_n \to k$ is a cocycle. Than there is an extension $\mathcal{X}$ representing the class of $f$ that is as small as $P$ is.

In more detail: Let $L := d_n(\ker(f)) \le P_{n-1}$ where $d_n: P_n \to P_{n-1}$. Then the class of $f$ is represented by the extension 
$$\mathcal{X}:\qquad 0 \to k \to P_{n-1}/L \to P_{n-2} \to \cdots \to P_0 \to k \to 0$$
(cf. page 9 of the paper Benson, Carlson: Projective resolutions and Poincaré duality complexes. Can be found on: http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/mth192/pages/html/archive/benson-carlson.html and holds for each augmented $k$-algebra $A$).

Usually one will try to choose $P$ as small as possible. If $A$ is Artinian (which holds for instance if $A=kG$ with $G$ finite) then each f.g. $A$-module has a projective cover. Hence $k$ has a minimal projective resolution which is a natural candidate for $P$.

If $A$ is only known to be Noetherian, one can construct a "small" resolution by computing a minimal generating set for $\ker(d_n)$ as $A$-module (let it have $k_n$ elements) and by choosing $P_{n+1} := A^{k_n}$ with the obvious map $P_{n+1} \twoheadrightarrow \ker(d_n) \hookrightarrow P_n$.

Comment: Thanks Ralph.  In the case of group cohomology, in playing around I was able to make $\mathcal{X}$ much smaller than the bar resolution, which obviously is not minimal.  However, I was hoping to make \mathcal{X} smaller than the resolution being used even if that resolution was itself minimal (in the sense of the algorithm from the last paragraph).  Is this something that can be done?  

Answer (score 1):

You ask for a way to make local changes to decrease the size of the extension.  Here are some observations for length two:

If $M \cap \operatorname{im} \iota = \{0\}$ then

$$ 0 \to k \stackrel \iota \to  A \stackrel j \to B \stackrel \pi \to k \to 0$$
is equivalent to 
$$ 0 \to k \to A/M \to B/j(M) \to k \to 0$$ via the obvious maps.  Equally if $N \leq B$ and $\pi|_N \neq 0$ then the sequence is equivalent to
$$0 \to k \to j^{-1}(N) \to N \to k \to 0$$

I imagine that using these is enough to reduce the size considerably in many cases.

Comment: I tried something like this but game up.  I don't think these are still exact.  Pick some 1-d $N$ which maps onto $k$, then $j^{-1}(N)=0$ but exactness, but $k\to 0$ is not injective.  Am I missing something?

Comment: $j$ has a kernel equal to $\operatorname{im} \iota$, so $j^{-1}(N)$ contains $\operatorname{im} \iota$ and is never zero.  In the case you describe, the sequence splits.

Comment: Good point, mt.  These are clearly exact.  